# How do I make more than two buttons in my web server with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, webserver

I'm trying to run a Pi Web Server to control an actuator. So here are some details about what I'm trying to do, my rpi(3B+) communicate with an Arduino Nano via XBee, rpi is master and nano is slave, via the Pi Web Server I want to write on the serial port by using buttons (6 in totals) then read what is written with  the nano and finally control the actuator...

I was following this tutorial : (https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-web-server-using-flask-to-control-gpios/) and I managed to control the actuator by making some modifications but I was stuck in the fact that I never used Flask framework and I'm a big newbie in Python. So I was only able to make the actuator move on the right and on the left.

In sum, I'm stuck because I don't really know how to create more than 2 button, I've tried but I get this error message that I don't really understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app2.py", line 121, in <module>
    @app.route("/<changePin24>/<action24>")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1250, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1221, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: action
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I show you my code just here:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# ajout du pilotage uart
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=3.0)
# /dev/ttyS0 et non AMA0 !

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pins4 = {
    4: {'name': 'GPIO 4', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
}

pins24 = {
    24: {'name': 'GPIO 24', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
}

pins17 = {
    17: {'name': 'GPIO 17', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
}

pins23 = {
    23: {'name': 'GPIO 23', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
}

pins22 = {
    22: {'name': 'GPIO 22', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
}

pins13 = {
    13: {'name': 'GPIO 13', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
}

# Set each pin as an output and make it low:
for pin4 in pins4:
    GPIO.setup(pin4, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin4, GPIO.LOW)

for pin24 in pins24:
    GPIO.setup(pin24, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin24, GPIO.LOW)

for pin17 in pins17:
    GPIO.setup(pin17, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin17, GPIO.LOW)

for pin23 in pins23:
    GPIO.setup(pin23, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin23, GPIO.LOW)

for pin22 in pins22:
    GPIO.setup(pin22, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin22, GPIO.LOW)

for pin13 in pins13:
    GPIO.setup(pin13, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin13, GPIO.LOW)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
    for pin4 in pins4:
        pins4[pin4]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin4)

    for pin24 in pins24:
        pins24[pin24]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin24)

    for pin17 in pins17:
        pins17[pin17]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin17)

    for pin23 in pins23:
        pins23[pin23]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin23)

    for pin22 in pins22:
        pins22[pin22]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin22)

    for pin13 in pins13:
        pins13[pin13]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin13)

    # Put the pin dictionary into the template data dictionary:
    templateData = {
    'pins4': pins4,
    'pins24': pins24,
    'pins17': pins17,
    'pins23': pins23,
    'pins22': pins22,
    'pins13': pins13,
    }
# Pass the template data into the template main.html and return it to the user
    return render_template('main.html', **templateData)

# The function below is executed when someone requests a URL with the pin number and action in it:
@app.route("/<changePin4>/<action4>")
def action(changePin4, action4):
# Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    changePin4 = int(changePin4)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.route("/<changePin24>/<action24>")
def action(changePin24, action24):
# Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    changePin24 = int(changePin24)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.route("/<changePin17>/<action17>")
def action(changePin17, action17):
# Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    changePin17 = int(changePin17)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.route("/<changePin23>/<action23>")
def action(changePin23, action23):
# Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    changePin23 = int(changePin23)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.route("/<changePin22>/<action22>")
def action(changePin22, action22):
# Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    changePin22 = int(changePin22)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The function below is executed when someone requests a URL with the pin number and action in it:
@app.route("/<changePin13>/<action13>")
def action(changePin13, action13):
# Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
    changePin13 = int(changePin13)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get the device name for the pin being changed:
    deviceName4 = pins4[changePin4]['name']
    deviceName24 = pins24[changePin24]['name']
    deviceName17 = pins17[changePin17]['name']
    deviceName23 = pins23[changePin23]['name']
    deviceName22 = pins22[changePin22]['name']
    deviceName13 = pins13[changePin13]['name']
# --------------------------------------------ACTIONNEUR HORIZONTAL---------------------------------
# Change the direction of the Actuator plugged on PWMA
# If the action part of the URL is "on," execute the code indented below:
    if action4 == "on":
    # Set the pin high:
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName4 + " on."
        port.write("HD")
    # horizontal right

    if action4 == "off":
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName4 + " off."
        port.write("SH")
    # stop
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if action24 == "on":
    # Set the pin high:
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
    # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName24 + " on."
        port.write("HG")
    # horizontal left

    if action24 == "off":
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName24 + " off."
        port.write("SH")
        #stop
#----------------------------------------------ACTIONNEUR VERTICAL-----------------------------------------------
#Change the direction of the actuator plugged on PWMB
    if action17 == "on":
    # Set the pin high:
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
    # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName17 + " on."
        port.write("VH")
    #vertical up

    if action17 == "off":
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName17 + " off."
        port.write("SV")
    #stop
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Change the direction of the actuator plugged on PWMB
    if action23 == "on":
      # Set the pin high:
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
 # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName23 + " on."
        port.write("VB")
         #vertical down

    if action23 == "off":
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName23 + " off."
        port.write("SV")
        #stop
#---------------------------------------------WHERE WE SET MOTOR'S SPEED--------------------------------------------
# Change the speed of PWM ===> Pulse Width Modulation
    if action22 == "on":
        # Set the pin high:
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
        # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName22 + " on."
        port.write("PWMmoyen")
        # Middle speed motor

    if action22 == "off":
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName22 + " off."
        port.write("SPWM")
        # stop
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Change the speed of PWM ===> Pulse Width Modulation
    if action13 == "on":
            # Set the pin high:
        GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
            # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
        message = "Turned " + deviceName13 + " on."
        port.write("PWMmax")
            # Middle speed motor

    if action13 == "off":
        GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
        message = "Turned " + deviceName13 + " off."
        port.write("SPWM")
        # stop
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
    for pin4 in pins4:
        pins4[pin4]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin4)

    for pin24 in pins24:
        pins24[pin24]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin24)

    for pin17 in pins17:
        pins17[pin17]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin17)

    for pin23 in pins23:
        pins23[pin23]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin23)

    for pin22 in pins22:
        pins22[pin22]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin22)

    for pin13 in pins13:
        pins13[pin13]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin13)

    #put pin's state in data dictionary:
    templateData = {
        'pins4': pins4,
        'pins24': pins24,
        'pins17': pins17,
        'pins23': pins23,
        'pins22': pins22,
        'pins13': pins13,
    }

    return render_template('main.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: @v25 Unfortunately in the current form this post would be off-topic on CR. Please hold on recommending users post there until you read and understand the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_".

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thanks for informing me, I'll check this out ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you use the same name for all the functions: `def action(changePinxx, actionxx):`

The functions for each view must have different names.  Next, we can talk about not using all the different functions.

These urls:

`/foo/bar`

`/hey/there`

have no way to know where to go.  Put them all in one function:

```
@app.route("/<number>/<changePin>/<action>")
def action(number, changePin, action):
    changePin = int(changePin)
    # now do something with changePin #number
```

Then, work on your dictionary:

```
pins = {
    4: {'name': 'GPIO 4', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
    24: {'name': 'GPIO 24', 'state': GPIO.LOW},
    etc.
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you to take your time to answer me! I'll try it out.